# WooCommerce display Product Attributes on shop page compatible with multi-language

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes, custom-taxonomy, wpml

I have managed to change WooCommerce to Show attributes on the shop page.
however, my site is multi-language, how can I make this function multi-language?

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_size_attribute', 5 );
function display_size_attribute() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
        $taxonomy = 'klasse-graafmachine-ton';
        echo '<span class="attribute-s">Klasse graafmachine (t): ' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>','<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use **custom product attributes** (created locally on the product), you should use instead global product attributes taxonomies set globally on Product Attributes section.

[image]

Then configure terms for your product attribute...

Now on each product you will configure the Attribute (and select the term for it):

[image]

Now you can translate this product attribute and its terms in your multilingual plugin as it's a taxonomy like product category or product tag.

Then you can use the following revised code to display the attribute in archives:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_size_attribute', 5 );
function display_size_attribute() {
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'pa_klasse-graafmachine-ton';

    if ( $product->is_type('simple') && ( $term_name = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) ) ) {
        printf( '<span class="attribute-s">%s: %s</span><br>', wc_attribute_label($taxonomy, $product), $term_name );
    }
}
```

It should work.

**Note:** The taxonomy to be used in the code will be *(starts always with "pa_")*.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the true. We have WPML and unfortunately we cannot translate this string.

Comment: It's not a standard option that woocommerce shows a product attribute on the shopping page with all the products (so not the product page itself). I had to add the script at the functions.php so the attribute is visible on the shop page.

Comment: I have updated my answer… It will work with WPML.